# SwiftUI Runtime Error from if condition { Text() } in watchOS

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

As far as I read about conditional Views this code should work. But it doesn't.

```
struct Consts {
    static let myCondition = false //no difference if true or false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var toggle: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            Text("Short Text is in first line")
            Text("Second Line Text is a little longer but not much")
            if Consts.myCondition {
                Text("This is a conditional text. As in: when the user hasn't purchased the option he / she don't need a hint how to use this feature.")
//            } else {
//                Text("else doesn't help either.")
            }
            Toggle("I also have a toggle but it has nothing to do with this.", isOn: $toggle)
            Text("Here we have a longer Text. Dont know what to type any more.")
            Text("More text which is longer than a few lines.")
            Text("Not so long Text")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Hints & Settings")
    }
}
```

It compiles without warnings or errors. It loads up and displays fine, on simulator and on device. But every time I scroll the List upwards from the end, as soon as this `if condition { Text() }` should become visible the app crashes with

```
Fatal error: file SwiftUI, line 0
2021-03-07 06:36:26.548126+0100 WTFif WatchKit Extension[23163:641812] Fatal error: file SwiftUI, line 0
```

This is not limited to watchOS. It reproduces the same way in iOS, just the Texts have to be longer so that the `if condition { Text() }` becomes invisible when scrolling.

I have worked around the error with an array, conditional ranges and two ForEach() blocks.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let myHints = ["Short Text is in first line",
                   "Second Line Text is a little longer but not much",
                   "This is a conditional text. As in: when the user hasn't purchased the option he / she don't need to hint how to use this feature.",
                   "Here we have a longer Text. Dont know what to type any more.",
                   "More text which is longer than a few lines.",
                   "Not so long Text"]
    var myUpperRange: ClosedRange<Int> {
        if Consts.myCondition {
            return 0...1
        } else {
            return 0...2
        }
    }
    var myLowerRange: ClosedRange<Int> {
        return 3...5
    }
    @State var toggle: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List() {
            ForEach (myUpperRange, id: \.self) { i in
                Text(myHints[i])
            }
            Toggle("I also have a toggle but it has nothing to do with this.", isOn: $toggle)
            ForEach (myLowerRange, id: \.self) { i in
                Text(myHints[i])
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Hints & Settings")
    }
}
```

My question basically is: am I not getting it or did I find a bug in Xcode / SwiftUI? Should my code above work? What could I have done different to make it work with the simple list of Texts?

Background: I also have a TabView with an `if condition { MyTab() }` which works without crashing. Do I have to worry that this might crash in the same way? Should I work around this as well before shipping?

PS: I am using Xcode 12.4 (12D4e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this has been fixed by iOS 15 Beta 4: on my test device I had the error prior to the Beta 4 update, using a test app compiled with Xcode 13 Beta 3. After the update to iOS 15 Beta 4 the error is gone.
So I think it’s reasonable to say that the update to iOS 15 Beta 4 did fix the error.